# How to publish custom function for Google Spreadsheets developed using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on, custom-function

Please forgive me if I sound naive, I did read some tutorials on Google Script site.

I recently became aware of extending Google Spreadsheets functionality with custom functions using Google Script.

I understand the Script is tied to a particular Spreadsheet that one opens in Google Docs and using Tools menu to insert custom functions code. The Spreadsheet works like a container for custom functions code

The issue that I am having trouble understanding is how such functions are published and how do the end users discover availability of custom functions so that they can insert those custom functions in the spreadsheets they create

And is there a way to put together a collection of custom functions to work like a Functions Library or do we have to create individual functions and publish each one

Answer (score 1):

As you've mentioned, a custom function's availability is restricted to the spreadsheet under which the custom function was written until recently.

You can now create Libraries of the functions and make them available for other spreadsheets to use by the script ID - More details in the documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how the Script ID is used in distributing the functions to other spreadsheet users. What I have come away with by reading the links you mentioned is that source code is visible to the users who install a particular script in spreadsheet from the Script Gallery. This is the last thing I want having the code visible to anyone. I would have thought that only the function calls will be exposed to the spreadsheet that is using the library thus allowing others to insert any of the functions in the library. Or have I misunderstood the way custom functions are used?

Answer (score 1):

If you publish your script to the [Script Gallery](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/publishing_gallery) it can be discovered and installed by other users. They will have a copy of the script's source installed into their spreadsheet.